# HTML5 Geolocation shows wrong speed

Tags: html, gps, geolocation

I'm using [HTML5 Geolocation](http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html) to show information about visitors GPS information. When I tested the function yesterday while I sat in a bus, the speed showed under 25 km/h when the bus went over 70 km/h. Why?

Comment: I hope you did not interchange meter per second with km/h.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html geolocation delivers speed in m/s.

70 km/h bus speed are 70/3.6 = 19.4 m/s.

That is near to 25, so that could be a reason.

However there are more causes, most likely to be related to bad GP Ssignal receivement. placing the phone very near the window should work.
However some windows shield the GPS signal, but I saw that only in trains.